# trying to stop execution for 2 seconds

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a button and when clicked calls a method which starts a thread. but there is stop for that thread, fine. I want that to complete the thread first then to execute the rest of the code.

I tried to use wait() but not working.

```
public void configure(Button arg0,TextView arg1) throws InterruptedException{

    //calling OpenDeviceListener
    readText=arg1;
    button= arg0;

    //handler
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.d("Handler","running");
            if (actualNumBytes != 0x00) {
                Log.d("handler","if");
                readText.append(String.copyValueOf(readBuffer, 0,
                        actualNumBytes));
                Log.d("handler","if 312");
                actualNumBytes = 0;
                Log.d("handler","if end");
            }
            Log.d("handler","closed");
        }
    };


    Log.d("163","tab");
    uartInterface = new CH34xAndroidDriver(
            (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE), this,
            ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
    Log.d("167","tab");
    act_string = getIntent().getAction();
    if(-1 != act_string.indexOf("android.intent.action.MAIN"))
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "android.intent.action.MAIN 171");
    } 
    else if(-1 != act_string.indexOf("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"))
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED 175");
    }

    if(!uartInterface.UsbFeatureSupported())
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Support USB host API", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("182","tab");
        readText.setText("No Support USB host API");
        Log.d("184","tab");
        uartInterface = null;
    }

    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    if(READ_ENABLE == false) {
        READ_ENABLE = true;
        Log.d("192","tab");
        handlerThread = new readThread(handler);
        handlerThread.start();
    }
    Log.d("192","End");
    try{
    this.wait(100);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Exception",e.getMessage());
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("205","OpenDeviceListener");
                boolean flags;
                if(false == isConfiged) {
                    Log.d("209","OpenDeviceListener");
                    Toast.makeText(global_context,""+((Boolean)uartInterface.isConnected()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    isConfiged = true;
            //      writeButton.setEnabled(true);
                    if(uartInterface.isConnected()) {
                        Toast.makeText(global_context,""+(Boolean)uartInterface.isConnected(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("213","OpenDeviceListener");
                        flags = uartInterface.UartInit();
                        if(!flags) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Init Uart Error 2");
                            Toast.makeText(global_context, "Init Uart Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            if(uartInterface.SetConfig(baudRate, dataBit, stopBit, parity, flowControl)) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Configed");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
}
```

and plz clear one thing the stop() is not called for the thread, up to when the thread will run.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
//this method will be called after 2 seconds
                            //do your task here
                        }
                    };
                    final Handler h = new Handler();
                    h.removeCallbacks(runnable); // cancel the running action (the
                                                    // hiding process)
                    h.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Object lock = new Object;
synchronized(lock){
    lock.wait();
}
```

this will block current Thread running these code.
when it's time notify the blocked code

```
synchronized (lock) {
    lock.notify();
}
```

if just want to sleep the thread for a specific time why not use

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Comment: no i don't wan't to stop thread, i want to stop the execution of main code which is after the threat call. Should i just put a new thread class and run that in the new thread using wait().

Comment: start a thread in your main thread first run it using thread.start(); then thread.join(); then the main thread would continue to run after your thread is complete.